# Performance - Select query with left join and null check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables which are called as `Processing (30M records for now)` and `EtlRecord (4.3M records for now)`.
As the name of tables suggest, these tables will be used for normalization of data with ETL.

We are trying to process records with batches where we have 1000 records in each batch.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 P.StreamGuid
FROM [staging].[Processing] P           (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN [core].[EtlRecord] E          (NOLOCK)    ON E.StreamGuid = P.StreamGuid
WHERE E.StreamGuid IS NULL
AND P.CompleteDate IS NOT NULL
AND P.StreamGuid IS NOT NULL
```

Execution of this query takes around 20 seconds now. And we are expecting to have more and more data especially in EtlRecord table. To be able to improve the performance of this query I check the actual execution plan which I shared below.

[image: Execution plan]

As you can see, the most time consuming part is index seek to determine null records in EtlRecord table. I have tried several changes but couldn't able to improve it.

**Additional notes**

- All suggested indices by execution plan already applied to tables. So there is no further index suggestion.
- There are 8 columns in `Processing` table which are mostly boolean flags and 4 columns in `EtlRecord` table.
- EtlRecord table is only used by single procedure. So there is no issue with transaction lock.

Any suggestions to improve this query will be really helpful.

Comment: Change to `NOT EXISTS` so that it doesn't outer join all the rows and then filter out all those except ones where `E.StreamGuid IS NULL`  - this might not solve all your issues as the nested loops could be the main problem but try that first. If still issues then try `USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL')` to see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tested `NOT EXISTS` but the execution plan was exactly same. So there is no performance improvement. Also because of my SQL Server version I can't able to use `DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL` hint.

Comment: Why are you importing a table of 30m records 1000 records at a time? If it takes 20 seconds to run your workflow for 1000 records, you're looking at 7 DAYS to process all 30m rows.

Comment: The execution plan won't be exactly the same. It will be an anti semi join . Not an outer join and filter. Regarding the row goal hint you can parameterise the `TOP` and set it to `OPTIMIZE FOR` a large number but pass in 1000 to achieve much the same

Comment: `DECLARE @top INT = 1000

SELECT TOP  (@top) P.StreamGuid
FROM [staging].[Processing] P
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT *
FROM [core].[EtlRecord] E
WHERE E.StreamGuid = P.StreamGuid
)
AND P.CompleteDate IS NOT NULL
AND P.StreamGuid IS NOT NULL
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@top = 0x7fffffff))` and a filtered index allowing the `P.CompleteDate IS NOT NULL and P.StreamGuid IS NOT NULL`  predicates to be resolved efficiently could be useful

Comment: I gave a try your solution it worked like a charm. Thank you so much @MartinSmith. Appromaxily it is around 5 seconds now, sometimes less than that. But I believe in the long run when data keep increasing I might encountered same performance issue again. So I'm planning to change my implementation. I'm planning to get rid off uniqueidentifier and will replace it with BIGINT, so I can keep latest processed record in the session and retrieve next batch without checking any data in EtlRecord table.

Comment: @MartinSmith can you put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your query you need to get records from `[staging].[Processing]` which has not got corresponding record in the `[core].[EtlRecord]`.

You can remove the proceeded records, first.

```
DELETE [staging].[Processing]
FROM [staging].[Processing] P           
INNER JOIN [core].[EtlRecord] E
    ON E.StreamGuid = P.StreamGuid;
```

You can use deletion on batches if you need. Removing this records will simplify our initial query and the nasty join by `uniqueidentifier`. You simply need to do then something like this for each batch:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 StreamGuid
INTO #buffer
FROM [staging].[Processing]
WHERE CompleteDate IS NOT NULL
    AND StreamGuid IS NOT NULL;

-- do whatevery you need with this records 

DELETE FROM [staging].[Processing]
WHERE StreamGuid IN (SELECT StreamGuid FROM #buffer);
```

Also, you have said that you have all indexes created but indexes suggested by the execution plan are not always best. This part here:

```
WHERE CompleteDate IS NOT NULL
    AND StreamGuid IS NOT NULL;
```

seems like very good candidate for [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) especially if large amount of the rows has a `NULL` value for one of this columns.

Comment: Thank you for your time but unfortunally it will not work in my case. We created seperated `EtlRecord` table to avoid table lock when inserting record on `Processing` table. Also tried to define filtered index but it didn't work as well. After all, null field belongs to result set not to table itself.

Answer (score 1):

First, DDL and easily consumable sample data, like below, will help a great deal. You can copy/paste my solutions and run them locally to see what I'm talking about.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#processing','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #processing;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EtlRecord','U')  IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EtlRecord;

SELECT TOP (100) 
  StreamGuid   = NEWID(),
  CompleteDate = CASE WHEN CHECKSUM(NEWID())%3 < 2 THEN GETDATE() END
INTO #processing
FROM sys.all_columns AS a

SELECT TOP (80) p.StreamGuid
INTO   #EtlRecord
FROM   #Processing AS p;

ALTER TABLE #processing ALTER COLUMN StreamGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE #EtlRecord  ALTER COLUMN StreamGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE #processing ADD CONSTRAINT pk_processing PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(StreamGuid);
ALTER TABLE #etlRecord  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_etlRecord  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(StreamGuid);
GO
```

Next understand that, without an ORDER BY clause, your query is not guaranteed to return the same records each time. For example, if SQL Server picks a parallel execution plan you will definitely get a different rows. I have also seen cases where including the ORDER BY will actually improve performance.

With that in mind, not that this...

```
SELECT --TOP 1000 
  P.StreamGuid
FROM      #processing AS p
LEFT JOIN #etlRecord  AS e ON e.StreamGuid = p.StreamGuid
WHERE     e.StreamGuid   IS NOT NULL
AND       P.CompleteDate IS NOT NULL
```

... will return the exact same thing as this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
  P.StreamGuid
FROM      #processing AS p
JOIN      #etlRecord  AS e ON e.StreamGuid = p.StreamGuid
WHERE     p.CompleteDate IS NOT NULL;
```

note that `WHERE e.StreamGuid = p.StreamGuid` already implies that both values are **NOT NULL**. Note that this query...

```
DECLARE @X INT;
SELECT  AreTheyEqual = IIF(@X=@X,'Yep','Nope');
```

... returns:

```
AreTheyEqual
------------
Nope
```

I agree with the solution @gotqn posted about the filtered index. Using my sample data, you can add something like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_processing ON #processing(CompleteDate,StreamGuid)
    WHERE CompleteDate IS NOT NULL;
```

Then you can add an `ORDER BY CompleteDate` to the query to coerce the optimizer into choosing it that index (on my system it doesn't pick the index unless I add an ORDER BY). The ORDER BY will make you query deterministic and more predictable.

Comment: Thanks for your time by replaying the question. But as I already commented @gotqn answer, filtered index will not work in my case. I'm not trying to filter out null records in EtlRecord table, I'm trying to get next 1000 records which are not exits in EtlRecord table from Processing table

Comment: @Serdar - the rows from Processing table that do not meet `P.CompleteDate IS NOT NULL AND P.StreamGuid IS NOT NULL` don't need to be read  or participate in the join, this is how the filtered index can help

Comment: @serdar sorry, I missed your comment under what gotqn posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 P.StreamGuid
FROM [staging].[Processing] P
WHERE P.CompleteDate IS NOT NULL AND
      P.StreamGuid IS NOT NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [core].[EtlRecord] E 
                  WHERE E.StreamGuid = P.StreamGuid
                 );
```

I removed the `NOLOCK` directive.  Only use it if you really know what you are doing -- and are prepared to read invalid data.

Then you definitely want an index on `EtlRecord(StreamGuid)`.

You probably also want an index on `Processing(CompleteDate, StreamGuid)`.  This is at least a covering index for the query.

Comment: Topical: [SQL Server results differ: NOT IN versus LEFT JOIN with IS NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61828891/2943403)