# SQL Server results differ: NOT IN versus LEFT JOIN with IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, notin

I ran into a problem today that I couldn't quite understand, so I was hoping for some outside knowledge. I was trying to find the number of items in a table where their id isn't referenced in another. I ran two different queries and seem to have conflicting results.

```
select count(*)
from TableA
where ID not in (select aID from TableB)
```

returns 0

```
select count(*)
from TableA a
left join TableB b on b.aID = a.ID
where b.aID is null
```

returns a few thousand.

All IDs in both TableA and TableB are unique. An ID from TableA never shows up in the aID column from TableB more than once. To me, it seems like I am querying the same thing but receiving different results. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Clearly this can be expected to be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `not in` with a subquery.  If *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`, then *all* rows are filtered out.  These are the rules of how `NULL` is defined in SQL.  The `LEFT JOIN` is correct.

The reason is that `NULL` means an unknown value.  Almost any comparison with `NULL` returns `NULL`, which is treated as false.  So, the only possibilities with `NOT IN` with `NULL` are that an element matches what you are looking for -- and the expression returns `false` -- or an element is `NULL` -- and the expression returns `NULL` which is treated as `false`.

I usually advise replacing the `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select count(*)
from TableA a
where not exists (select 1 from TableB b where b.aID = a.ID);
```

The `LEFT JOIN` performs correctly and usually has good performance.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. When I changed it to ```ID not in (select aID from TableB where aID is not null)``` worked too. But using exists is probably a good habit for me to get in

Comment: @bds212 . . . The `WHERE` clause definitely fixes the problem.  I prefer `NOT EXISTS`, but if you get in the habit of using it, you just don' have to worry about `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

We should always use the EXISTS operator if the columns involved are nullables. Also,Exist is faster than In clause.

Using IN/Not IN operator might produce an inferior plan and also can lead to misleading results if a null value is inserted in the table just like in you case.